# Primitive types cloud endpoints

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using Google Cloud Endpoints for my Android application, and I have created a `Message` entity thanks to the datastore.

However I saw in many threads that primitive types are a known issue and one of my `Message`'s fields is a `int[]`.

Will it work, or do I have to use `List` (`Integer`) instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return `Message` object which contains primitive fields, but you cannot return primitive field like `int`, `float` or even `String`.

The endpoint will not compile if you have incompatibile return types so check if it works for you. I'm sure will be provided with meaningful error message when given type is not supported as result type.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to use the byte[] field but when I generated the Endpoints libs, it converted the getter and the setter to String and added some encodeBase64 methods. 
I tried to use those but it doesn't work, the error is "Message: com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Illegal character '_' (code 0x5f) in base64 content"

Comment: Byte[] is still not the appropriate type. Why don't you convert the Integers to Strings and then send them?